# Is there any way to run my .exe file from pyinstaller on a Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to convert my .py project into a executable file. I got it to finally work, but I also want to be able to use this project on a Mac. Is there any way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: .exe files are Windows specific. Mac isn't Windows.

Comment: There is no cross-building tool for Python, the platform you build the executable the platform it runs.